# Given a die what's the probability you roll each value twice in 12 rolls?

Tags: statistics

So if you have a normal die with 6 sides each value having a 1/6 chance of occurring, what is the probability of it landing on each value twice?

Also how would you compare the probability of a results such as (1:3, 2:1, 3:0, 4:0, 5:5, 6: 3)       [1:0 means the value "1" happened "0" times)  ?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting exactly two 1's on 12 rolls is
${12\choose 2} (\frac 16)^2 (\frac 56)^{10}$

The probability of getting exactly two 1's and two 2's on 12 rolls is
${12\choose 2,2} (\frac 16)^2 (\frac 16)^2 (\frac 46)^8$

can you see where this is going?